# How to recover an address from the signed message?

Tags: android, trust

I use Trust SDK for signing messages and transactions.

I recover a transaction (`Trust.signTransaction()`) like this:

```
val tx = Geth.newTransactionFromRLP(Numeric.hexStringToByteArray(response.result))
```

Where `Geth` - framework (org.ethereum.geth), version 1.8.11.

How can I recover a data (and an address of the user's wallet) from the signed message (`Trust.signMessage()`)?

Developer of Trust SDK said to look at 'recovery'. But what is it? Framework?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem.

1) Need to use this approach:

```
signPersonalMessageCall = Trust.signPersonalMessage()
                .message("my message to be signed")
                .call(this)
```

2) To get the address of the user need to use:

```
const val PERSONAL_MESSAGE_PREFIX = "\u0019Ethereum Signed Message:\n"    

//...

fun recoverAddressFromSignature(message: String, signature: String): String? {
            val prefix = PERSONAL_MESSAGE_PREFIX + message.length
            val msgHash = Hash.sha3((prefix + message).toByteArray())

            val signatureBytes = Numeric.hexStringToByteArray(signature)
            var v = signatureBytes[64]

            if (v < 27) {
                v = (v + 27).toByte()
            }

            val sd = SignatureData(
                    v,
                    Arrays.copyOfRange(signatureBytes, 0, 32) as ByteArray,
                    Arrays.copyOfRange(signatureBytes, 32, 64) as ByteArray)

            var addressRecovered: String? = null

            // Iterate for each possible key to recover
            for (i in 0..3) {
                val publicKey = Sign.recoverFromSignature(
                        i,
                        ECDSASignature(BigInteger(1, sd.r), BigInteger(1, sd.s)),
                        msgHash)

                if (publicKey != null) {
                    addressRecovered = "0x" + Keys.getAddress(publicKey)

                    Log.i(Core.APP_TAG, "*-*-* addressRecovered = $addressRecovered")
                }
            }

            return addressRecovered
        }
```

The method (on Java) for recovering was grabbed from [here](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/ed2ca03335ad2cb3316314303746b70b456b0d68/crypto/src/test/java/org/web3j/crypto/ECRecoverTest.java).